# The leading comma in `complex([real[, imag]])`

Tags: python

In documentation's guideline:
[2. Built-in Functions — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

```
dir([object])
```

It's obvious that `[object]` means it's an object inside bracket.

as for

```
class bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])
class complex([real[, imag]])
```

Search it,the results cycle back to the offical documentation.

What's syntax behind 'leading comma'?

Comment: Are you asking about documentation meta-syntax?

Comment: *“It's obvious that `[object]` means it's an object inside bracket.”* Well, that’s not what it means, so I guess it’s not that obvious. Bracketed parameters are optional.

Comment: No, when the Python documentation states `dir([object])` it does _not_ imply that you need to supply an argument within a list. When arguments are presented in *`[brackets]`* , they are optional and can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear with me but I'm going to cite a bit here (emphasis mine):

> #### dir(*[object]*)
>
> **Without arguments**, return the list of names in the current local scope. **With an argument**, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object. ([Python 3.6.3 Documentation source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir))

The above notation for the Python documentation implies that the parameter, `object`, is *optional* and supplying it affects the behavior of the method (as described in `dir()`'s description).

As for your example of `complex([real[, imag]])`, the syntax indicates that it is valid for you to supply *none, only `real`, or both* of the arguments. The behaviors of the method under those circumstances are also listed in the method's description (emphasis also mine):

> ...**If `imag` is omitted**, it defaults to zero and the constructor serves as a numeric conversion like int and float. **If both arguments are omitted**, returns `0j`. ([PyDocs source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex))

However, be careful as this is not the same as `complex([real, imag])`. `complex([real, imag])` only implies that you can supply *either none or both* of the arguments, not any single one of them.

Hope this helped!

Comment: an impressive tuorial

Comment: @DFK Glad that I could help :)